# Converting image pixels to a list so that I can use .map() function

Tags: google-earth-engine

There is an image that is a 2-dimension matrix of the pixel values, and I want to do some operations for each pixel.

```
// For each pixel i (i = 1,..., N) in the image, the pixel value is P_i;
// For the other pixels j (j != i) in the image, P_j = P_j - P_i;     
// For a given value q, if (P_j < q) P_j = 1; else P_j = 0;     
// Finally, P_i = sum(P_j);

//The code provided by JonasV is a version aimed at only one pixel i.    
//However, what I want is that every pixel in the image (total number is N) do the same calculation.     
//Therefore, it seems need a list to contain these pixels firstly.    
//because the value of pixel i is a variable, not a constant.


var i = ee.Image(5)  //i indicates the value of one pixel i in the image    
var j = ee.Image(2)  //j indicates the other pixels j (j!=i) in the image

var j_2 = j.subtract(i)

var q = ee.Number(3)

var j_3 = j_2.lt(q)

Map.addLayer(j_3)
```

Therefore, I think I need to arrange these pixels into a list, in order to use `.map()` function.

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Please provide a minimal script showing what you're trying to do.

Comment: To do operations on each pixel of an image, you do operations on the images (e.g. `image1.multiply(10)` works on each pixel); converting to a list would be extremely inefficient by comparison. Could you [edit] your question to describe _what you want to do to each pixel?_ Then we can advise on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your advices!  I have edited the question.

Comment: I don't follow this. Can you explain this in more detail? Please, also include some context of what you're trying to achive.

Comment: The code  provided by JonasV is a version aimed at only one pixel i. However, what I want is that every pixel in the image  (total number is N) do the same calculation. Therefore, it seems need a list to contain these pixels firstly.

Answer (score 1):

For this you don't need to convert to a list. You can calculate on the image values directly. Here's a minimal example:

```
// For each pixel i (i = 1,..., N) in the image, the pixel value is P_i; 
// For the other pixels j (j != i) in the image, P_j = P_j - P_i; 
// For a given value q, if (P_j < q) P_j = 1; else P_j = 0; 
// Finally, P_i = sum(P_j);

var i = ee.Image(5)
var j = ee.Image(2)

var j_2 = j.subtract(i)

var q = ee.Number(3)

var j_3 = j_2.lt(q)

Map.addLayer(j_3)
```

I would suggest to start by reading the Earth Engine documentation. If you are Chinese, there are also some course materials available in Chinese [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/edu). But I can't tell you how good they are.

Comment: The code you provided is aimed at only one pixel i. However, what I want is that every pixel (total number is N) in the image do the same calculation. Therefore, it seems need a list to contain these pixels firstly.

Comment: No, the code I provided also works for N pixels, if they spatially overlap. Try it out in the Code editor, or watch some tutorials about how earth engine works

Comment: Yes, var i can be for N pixels, however, these N pixels have the constant value 5. In my case, the value of i is variable. For example, the image contains 20 pixels and their values range from 1 to 20, respectively. The values of these 20 pixels all need to be assigned to var i sequentially.

Comment: Moreover, the image is a mosaic of pixels, just like a picture. So these pixels can not spatially overlap.

Comment: Okay, different example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/bc3276c158d8e2e8d8d4f8e783d3bb2c

Comment: But please, if you still do not get it, please start out with reading the documentation/do the tutorials here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials

Comment: Ok, I see . You have misunderstood my question. Please read the question more carefully. What I wrote is "There is an image that is a 2-dimension matrix of the pixel values", which means just one image, not two different images in your code.

Comment: Okay. Then use ee.Image.reduceRegion() with the reducer ee.Reducer.toList(). However this won't work for very big regions.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your instruction. It seems a good solution! I will try it.